# Setting UP Spark on existing EC2 cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, apache-spark

I have to access some big files in buckets in Amazon S3 and do processing on them. For this I was planning to use Apache Spark. I have 2 EC2 instances for this learning project. These are not used but for small crons, so could I use them to install and run Spark? If so, how to install Spark on existing EC2 boxes, so that I can make one master and one slave?

Comment: What flavor of linux are you running?  This link details the basic Spark setup on Ubuntu 
http://blog.prabeeshk.com/blog/2014/10/31/install-apache-spark-on-ubuntu-14-dot-04/

Comment: Thanks, went through this site, but this does not create a master slave structure. Its for a local setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it helps, I installed Spark in standalone mode on one branch, and the other as well, setting one as Master, and the other as slave. The detailed instructions for the same as I followed are 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/spark-standalone.html#installing-spark-standalone-to-a-cluster

Answer (score 0):

See the tutorial on Apache Spark Cluster on EC2 here http://www.supergloo.com/fieldnotes/apache-spark-cluster-amazon-ec2-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

yes you can create easily a master slave with 2 aws instances just set SPARK_MASTER_IP = instance_privateIP_1 in spark-env.sh on both instances and put instance2 private ip in slaves file in conf folder and these configurations are same on both the machine and other configurations also set like memory core etc. and then you can start it from master, and make sure the spark is install on same location in both the machines.

Comment: you can take reference from this article just change ip from aws instances http://blog.knoldus.com/2015/04/14/setup-a-apache-spark-cluster-in-your-single-standalone-machine/